# Winforms, does holding a large collection of objects in memory violate good MVP practices?

Tags: .net, winforms, memory, memory-management, mvp

Would it break the MVP pattern to hold a large collection of objects in the presentation layer, or would it be better to retreive the information for the view from a datasource (in this case an xml document) as and when an event occurs?

Comment: Is that DataSource part of your Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no silver bullet. If you want to provide a quick response - load as much data as you can and as early as possible. If you want to reduce traffic & server payload - use event-driven scenarios. If you're loading data from **local** xml document (which is pretty cheap if your xml is not huge) then I do not see much difference - do whatever is more convinient.

I doubt anything more specific can be said.